# Dynamically created Bootstrap 3.3 paginator not centering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

So just to clarify one thing first: Yes I know Bootstrap has a new version. My class is using Bootstrap 3.3 because I believe they developed their curriculum before v4 was released.

Now that that's out of the way here is my question: When I was developing my HTML shell for my project, I put a <div> around my <nav> element and used the text-center helper class to center the paginator. It worked fine. However, I intended for this paginator to have dynamically created buttons depending on the number of results, so I deleted all of the <li> elements. Now, after running the javascript, the paginator no longer centers.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination paginationHolder">
            <!-- Dynamically created buttons will go here -->
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

and here is the javascript that builds the paginator:

```
//setup paginator, use do while so at least 1 page button is created
function paginationBuilder() { 
    //prev button
    $(".paginationHolder").empty()
    $(".paginationHolder").append("<li><a id='pgPrev' aria-label='Previous'><span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span></a></li>");
    totalPages = 0;
    do {
        totalPages++;
        $(".paginationHolder").append("<li><a data-pagenum='" + totalPages + "' class='pgBtn'>" + totalPages + "</a></li>");
    } while (totalPages < Math.ceil(searchResults.length / displayPerPage));
    //next button
    $(".paginationHolder").append("<li><a id='pgNext' aria-label='Next'><span aria-hidden='true'>&raquo;</span></a></li>");
    $(".paginationHolder").css("display", "inline");
}
```

I'm not entirely certain why it is behaving this way. Also, in case anyone want's to see the page in action: https://lordkriegan.github.io/Giphster/

Comment: If you add `display: inline-block` to the nav element then that should resolve the issue.

Comment: Even though your class is using 3.3 I would switch to 3.7. It is still the same major release, but it has a lot of bug fixes.

Comment: Simon: Thanks that was driving me insane!
bassxzero: actually we are. my apologies, i missed a couple keys when i was typing out my question. Thanks though.

Comment: @Simon do you mind explaining why this didn't work? I don't understand why it worked before it was being dynamically created, and not after.

Comment: Looking at the code again in more detail. Changing the line `$(".paginationHolder").css("display", "inline");` to `$(".paginationHolder").css("display", "inline-block");` should solve the problem. It looks to me like the inline is creating the issue.